# Paste from the clipboard in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, titanium, titanium-mobile

So I have 2 apps. One is a sensors app (built with XCode) that records data (text) with hardware wireless sensors. The other is a checklist/reference manual (built with Titaniam Appcelerator). Using custom URL schemes, they can instantiate each other.

What I am trying to do is paste any text data the sensors app copies to the clipboard into a text field in the reference manual app. I have a UIWebview showing html pages (the checklist) with a text box displayed now. To demo the capability, I have to touch the field and select paste. I was thinking that javascript might work, but all my research poo poo's that idea. Any thoughts about how to grab the text that is on the clipboard and display it programmatically in the reference manual app without having to touch the field and select paste?

Should I even be looking at the clipboard or should I be looking into modifying the custom URL scheme to pass data that way instead?

Answer (score 7):

To get the text from the clipboard:

```
UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
NSString *string = pasteboard.string;
if (string) {
    // Do something
}
```

For more funcional communication between apps, take a look at [URL Schemes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899).

Comment: I thought of this, however, the team I am supporting uses Titanium Appcelerator for the reference app. Once it does all the translation, I have to handle all the events in an embedded HTML page. Its a big fat PAIN!

Comment: I just added some info about URL Schemes for proper communication between apps. I don't understand your problem. Maybe you should ask a different question.

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured out a way to pass the data in the url with this [tutorial](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html). At the bottom it describes how to pass data after you set up the URL id for each app. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

**Pasting in Swift**

Get the pasteboard string with `UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().string`.

The string is optional, so it must be unwrapped before being used.

```
if let pasteboardString = UIPasteboard.generalPasteboard().string {

    // use the string, for example:
    myTextView.insertText(pasteboardString)
}
```

**Note**

- The original question is asking for something more complex than this. However, most people come here based on the question title rather than question content, so that I what I am answering here.